# Drupal 7 no me coje archivo css en form

Tags: php, css, drupal, drupal7

Estoy realizando un formulario en Drupal 7, en un modulo custom creado por mi.

Mi modulo tiene un nombre como *example_auxiliar_resource* (la carpeta que va a en modules), aunque luego en el .info lo especifico de forma correcta: *Example Auxiliar Resource*.

En una parte del form, inyecto codigo html para tener un par de campos en un div, para organizarlo facilmente con css.
Este fragmento se encuentra en mi archivo example_auxiliar_resource.inc

```
$form['offer_studies_minimun'] = array(
'#prefix' => '<div class="bloqueprim">
  <div class="estudios">',

'#suffix' => '</div>',  
'#type' => 'select',
'#title' => "Estudios mas adecuados",
'#options' => array(
  0 => t('Selecciona titulacion'),
  1 => t('E.S.O'),
  2 => t('Bachillerato'),
  3 => t('Grado medio de Informatica'),
  4 => t('Grado Superior de Informatica'),
  5 => t('Grado de Ingenieria Informatica'),
  6 => t('Master Informatica'),
),    
);


  $form['offer_studies_especial'] = array(
'#prefix' => '<div class="especialidad">',
'#suffix' => '</div></div>', 
'#type' => 'textfield', 
'#title' => t('Especialidad'),
'#required' => TRUE,
'#default_value' => !empty($form_state['values']['offer_studies_especial']) ? $form_state['values']['offer_studies_especial'] : '',
 );
```

El código css que quiero añadir es este (para alinearlos horizontalmente)

```
div{
width: 200px;
padding: 25px 0;
margin: 0;
}

.main{
background: red;
}

#bloqueprim{  /*padre*/
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%; 
}
#bloqueprim .estudios, #bloqueprim .especialidad{  /*hijos*/
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Según he visto en la documentación, hay diferentes formas de hacerlo.
Como estoy en drupal 7, el metodo `drupal_add_css()` sigue funcionando.
Pero a mi no me funciona ninguno de los métodos.

He probado con:

```
drupal_get_path('module', 'example_auxiliar_resource') . 'css/style.css';
```

al principio de la pagina. (del codigo .inc)
También lo he puesto en el .info tal cual, pero sigue sin ir.

También he probado

```
$form['#attached']['css'] = array(
 drupal_get_path('module', 'example_auxiliar_resource') . 'css/style.css',    
);
```

dentro del formulario, y no va.
Y un par de formas mas que también me han fallado.

Que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0):

En el .info de tu módulo debes incluir esta línea

stylesheets[all][] = tuarchivo.css

Donde pone 'tuarchivo.css' sustitúyelo por la ruta donde se encuentra tu archivo CSS, el cual debe estar dentro de la carpeta raíz del módulo

Te dejo un ejemplo https://www.drupal.org/node/800384